# What is the best way to save fastText word vectors in a dataframe as numeric values?

Tags: python, dataframe, vector, word-embedding, fasttext

**How to save fastText word vectors in dataframe better in order to use them for further calculations?**

Hello everyone!

I have a question about *fastText* word vectors, namely, I'd like to know, how to save them in my *dataframe* as vectors, but not objects. I want the column with word vectors be a numeric value as my next step is to calculate the average between different word forms.

Right now I use the following line to save word vectors into my dataframe:

```
full_forms["word_vec"] = full_forms.apply(lambda row: ft.get_word_vector(row["word_sg"]), axis=1)
```

After getting word vectors I try to calculate the average but it does not work:

```
full_forms["average"] = full_forms.apply(lambda row: row["word_vec":"word_vec_pl"].mean(axis=0))
```

One of the ideas is to save word vectors to a *list*, then this list will be *numpy.ndarray*. But I am not sure, whether it is a good choice. I expect this array to have 300 dimentions as fastText word vectors have 300 dimentions, but, when I check the number of dim with arr.ndim attribute, I get 1. Shouldn't it be 300?

That's me first time asking for help here, so sorry if it is too messy.
Thank you for help in advance!
Have a nice day!
Ana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For further calculations, usually the best approach is to *not* move the vectors into a `DataFrame` at all - which brings up these sorts of type/size issues, and adds more indirection & data-structure overhead from the `DataFrame`'s table/cells model.

Rather, leave them as the `numpy.ndarray` objects they are – either the individual 300-dimension arrays, or in some cases the giant `(number_of_words, vector_size)` matrix used by the FastText model itself to store all the words.

Using `numpy` functions directly on those will generally lead to the most concise & efficient code, with the least memory overhead.

For example, if `word_list` is a Python list of the words whose vectors you want to average:

```
average_vector = np.mean([ft.get_word_vector(word) for word in word_list], axis=0)
```